# How to only input a result and go down a cell if true

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I did not know how to explain it properly in 1 line, so I am sorry in advanced for the terrible title.

I have a sheet with 15k values, some of which are N/A while others are varied values, I would like to test if a value is N/A, and if so, input it into another row, with my limited knowledge I only know how to do it in a way that inputs 1 value if true, and another if false, which means that in my result sheet I will have few cells with vital information among thousands of cells that are contain a symbol for false result such as 0.

Comment: You could use macro/VBA to loop through the sheet. You could likely do with with a function as well, but to give any specifics, some examples on what you have and the desired result helps a lot.

Comment: There is a function named: **IFNA**, you can try it. https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/isna.php